# TemplateDoesNotExist after include

Tags: django, templates

I have a lot of templates in my project, all of them are nested inside `templates/myapp/` folder. And normally `Django` renders them all, except one template in which I try to `include` another template. That another template is also inside `templates/myapp/` folder, however, in this case `Django` throws me an error `TemplateDoesNotExist`. I do including like this:

```
  {% with template_name=program|add:".html" %}
      {% include template_name %}
  {% endwith %}
```

The resulting template name is correct. I see it on the error page.

**EDIT**

Ouch! I did it using `settings.py`. Always read documentation!

Comment: what you mean by ``I did it using settings.py`` ?

Comment: I specified TEMPLATE_DIRS

Comment: why dont you include in normal way? why with ``with``?

Comment: It is a nested template. There is some reason to do it in my app.